# Does an infinite sequence of random numbers have an infinite number of convergent subsequences?

Tags: real-analysis

Does an infinite sequence of random real numbers between 0 and 1 have an infinite number of convergent sub sequences each with its own limiting value?

Comment: my bad, i meant to say with different limiting values

Answer (score 2):

For any nonempty open set $U$ in the interval, the probability that a random sequence of reals never lands in $U$ is zero (assuming the usual probability distribution). So in fact with probability one a random sequence of reals contains a subsequence converging to $r$ for **every** $r\in[0,1]$.

A bit more precisely: for every nontrivial open subinterval of $[0,1]$, the set of sequences (of reals in $[0,1]$) intersecting it has measure $1$. Now we want to conclude that in fact measure one many sequences meet every such interval; this isn't immediate, since the intersection of a large collection of measure one sets need not have measure one (consider $\bigcap_{x\in[0,1]}[0,1]\setminus\{x\}$), but we can reduce to a countable collection of intervals - namely, those with rational endpoints. Measure one many sequences meet every nonempty open interval in $[0,1]$ with rational endpoints, and since every nonempty open interval in $[0,1]$ contains such an interval, the stronger result we wanted is in fact true. It's now easy to check that any sequence which meets every nonempty open interval in $[0,1]$ contains subsequences converging to $r$ for every $r\in[0,1]$.

More snappily, what's really going on here is:

> Measure one many sequences have dense image, and any sequence with dense image has subsequences converging to any point.